# request.getParameter returns null in jsp in case of Chrome. Works fine in IE

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, request

I am getting a null value when I try request.getParameter(SPLIT_ACTION). This happens only for Chrome and works fine in case of IE. SPLIT_ACTION is a constant string with value = "Split".

This is my line of code:

```
<td><button onClick="window.location = '<%=request.getRequestURI() %>?action=<%=SPLIT_ACTION%>&composite=<%=vitalDef.getSyncId() %>';">Split</button></td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form method="POST" action="<%=request.getRequestURI() %>">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Vital Name</th>
    <th>Abbreviation</th>
    <th>Back-end ID</th>
    <th>Sort Order</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="compositeheader">
    <td colspan="2">COMPOSITE: <input type="text" name="name_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" value="    <%=vitalDef.getName() %>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="abbrev_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" value="<%=vitalDef.getAbbrevName() %>"/></td>
    <td><button onClick="window.location = '<%=request.getRequestURI() %>?action=    <%=SPLIT_ACTION%>&composite=<%=vitalDef.getSyncId() %>';">Split</button></td>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="text" name="sortorder_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" 
            value="<%=sortKeys.get(vitalDef) %>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="compositerow" id="comprow_<%=component.getId() %>">
    <td style="background-color: #ffffff"></td>
    <td><%=beDef.getName() %></td>
    <td><%=beDef.getAbbrevName() %></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="text" name="compsortorder_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>_<%=component.getId()%>" 
            value="<%=component.getSortOrder() %>"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="vitaldef <%= counter % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" %>" id="vitaldef_<%=vitalDef.getId() %>">
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="name_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" value="<%=vitalDef.getName() %>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="abbrev_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" value="<%=vitalDef.getAbbrevName() %>"/></td>
    <td><%=backendName%></td>
    <td align="right">
        <input type="text" name="sortorder_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>" 
            value="<%=sortKeys.get(vitalDef) %>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('vitaldef_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>').vitalDefId = <%=vitalDef.getId()%>;
    new Draggable('vitaldef_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>',{revert:true, ghosting: true});
    Droppables.add('vitaldef_<%=vitalDef.getId()%>',
        {'accept': 'vitaldef', 'hoverclass': 'droptarget',
         'onDrop': function (toMerge, me) {
            window.location = "<%=request.getRequestURI() %>?action=<%=MERGE_ACTION%>&item1=" + me.vitalDefId + "&item2=" + toMerge.vitalDefId;
         }
        });

</script>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="<%=RESORT_ACTION %>" onclick="return verifyFields();"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: show the form where you are submitting the values ?

Comment: Please check the parameters sent on the request using Chrome developer tools and check the the parameter ```Split``` is submitted if so chek the value.

Comment: Yes I checked in Chrome developer Tools, "Split" is being passed.

Comment: @san krish, I have added the code for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you have to add `return false;` and the end of `onClick` method of the `<button>` tag like follows.

```
<button onClick="window.location ='<%=request.getRequestURI() %>?action=<%=SPLIT_ACTION%>&composite=<%=vitalDef.getSyncId() %>';return false;">Split</button>
```

Without `return false;` its submitting the form since there is no input component with name Split you are getting null.

**Also you are using `request.getParameter(SPLIT_ACTION)` means `request.getParameter("Split")` but there is no parameter named `'Split'` thats why you are getting `null`. If you want the `'action'` paremeter use `request.getParameter("action")`**

Also you have to be carefull with `<button>` tag, IE and Chrome act differently in case of `<button>` tag.

```
<button name='action' value='add'>Add</button>
```

In the above example `request.getParameter("action");` returns `Add` in IE and `add` in Google chrome.

So the workaround is you have to mention same value for the attribute `value` of the button tag and the body of the button tag.

It should be.

```
<button name='action' value='Add'>Add</button>
```

Comment: I added the return false, it didn't work. Also, I have done the same with Split like you have with Add. Still doesn't work. Anything else maybe?

Comment: @namita i've updated the answer. Also check the code i used for testing [here](https://gist.github.com/seenukarthi/dbaebca0bf19e77de915)

Comment: Thanks so much! I had put the return false statement inside a function with the whole line. Now I just wrote it like you have and it worked. Thanks! :)